# Selenium Python Click on Logo Button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to click on a logo button after I've made some downloads, in order to return to the original page. But it doesn't work and it throws the following exception:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"brand.brand-bv"}
```

The structure is this:

```
<a class="brand brand-bv" href="https://workbench-c4.bazaarvoice.com">
  <span class="visuallyhidden">Bazaarvoice:</span>
</a>
```

My current code is this:

```
logo_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("brand.brand-bv")                                                      
logo_button.click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`brand` is also class, if you are using `css_selector` it need to have leading `.`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".brand.brand-bv")
```

`brand.brand-bv` means element with tag `brand` and `brand-bv` class

```
<brand class="brand-bv"/>
```

You can also add some wait for the element to load

```
logo_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".brand.brand-bv")))
```

You need to import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

Comment: Thank you! But same exception thrown..."NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".brand.brand-bv"}"

Comment: @user7362809 Updated my answer.

Comment: Timeout Exception this time :(

Comment: @user7362809 mmm... can you check if the element is inside `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: It isn't... I've updated my post with a screen shot with the structure

Comment: @user7362809 can you try `presence_of_element_located` with increased time out? `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".brand.brand-bv")))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182429/discussion-between-guy-and-user7362809).

Answer (score 0):

you can also try to achieve same using xpath as its more flexible to use,
find the element store it in var e, then check for its length if present then only click, you can also try using wait for element before actually click on it.

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//a[href='https://workbench-c4.bazaarvoice.com']")

if len(e) > 0
    e[0].click()
```

syntax is

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("*//TAGNAME[ATTRIBUTENAME='ATTIBVALUE']")
```

Comment: Adding asterisk as leading symbol doesn't make much sense actually

Comment: Exception thrown: "NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[href='https://workbench-c4.bazaarvoice.com']"}"